# Ruby on Rails - Issues with Iterating Through Twitter Gem Search Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-gem

I've been using the Twitter Streaming API for a while with no problems, but recently switched over to using the REST and am a bit confused.

I'm trying to iterate through the results of tweets using #vietnam. After [reading the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Search), it appears I should do this using the max_id.

```
max_id = 70978401017678643100000000000000 #very big number to start out with
i = 1
2.times do
  puts '----------SEARCHING WITH MAX_ID: ' + max_id.to_s
  $twitter.search('#vietnam', result_type: "recent", lang: 'en', geocode: "14.05832400,108.27719900,100000mi", count: 100, max_id: max_id).each do |tweet|
    puts "#{i} - tweet.id: " + tweet.id.to_s
    i += 1
    max_id = tweet.id if tweet.id < max_id
  end
end
```

Here are the results from the terminal:

```
----------SEARCHING WITH MAX_ID: 70978401017678643100000000000000
1 - tweet.id: 713034427027361794
2 - tweet.id: 713030624164982785
3 - tweet.id: 713027195015413760
4 - tweet.id: 713022173246582784
5 - tweet.id: 713021690989641728
6 - tweet.id: 713013561396764672
7 - tweet.id: 713010847166177280
8 - tweet.id: 712997640930197505
...
341 - tweet.id: 709784010176786432
----------SEARCHING WITH MAX_ID: 709784010176786432
342 - tweet.id: 709784010176786432
```

The geocode in the search query has a 100,000 mile radius from the center of Vietnam to ensure that it my results are not being limited by location. The problem is that during the second iteration, the results only return 1 tweet, the max_id from the last result.

I know there are more 341 tweets with #vietnam in English, as verified by Twitter's advanced search functionality:
https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en

What is wrong with my iteration technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's REST API only returns results from the past 7 days, it's possible only 341 tweets with #vietnam have been made in the last week. The advanced search has results from much further back.

Your method seems sound, try a less restrictive search with a simple or popular term that's been used thousands of times over the past week and see if you get more results.

Comment: I had no idea it restricted you to 7 days previous. Is there anyway to look further in the past? We're looking for a historical view.

Comment: @CHawk I'm afraid not, at least not with search. You can get specific user's tweets that go back further, but that's about it. Twitter is pretty restrictive about giving access to the entire tweet history. There are [some](http://sifter.texifter.com/) [sites](https://gnip.com/historical/) that allow you to look further back, but they tend to be pretty costly. You could start compiling tweets now and build up a history going forward, but depending what you want that's probably not too useful.

Comment: It struck me as strange that there would only be 341 tweets with #vietnam in the last 7 days because I can watch the live stream and there were 100+ in the last few hours. HOWEVER, `geocode: "14.05832400,108.27719900,100000mi"`, caused only tweets with a geocoding attached to it to be returned, and it appears only 341 tweets in the last week had geocoding. Not the results I was looking for, but you are correct! +50

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are performing the Search two separate times?

You are finding the lowest (oldest) tweet id in the first iteration, and searching for results older than that in the second iteration (which don't exist). Perhaps I misunderstood?

Comment: If I could get all tweets at once, that would be perfect, but it is my understanding that twitter limits the results per response. Therefore, I would have to iterate through the results. I expected to get results 1-100 the first iteration, and results 101-200 the second...etc